# Ubuntu server dhcp - duplicate leases

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp-server

So we have an ubuntu server running DHCP & DNS managed through webmin (because it's less effort )

Nothing is BROKEN, but I noticed duplicate leases showing.  Anyone know why and how I can prevent that from happenning?

e.g. this android phone shows twice

```
10.56.9.120 90:21:55:c9:4b:75   android_200142972d3b1451    2012/01/19 06:17:25 2012/01/19 07:17:25
10.56.9.120 90:21:55:c9:4b:75   android_200142972d3b1451    2012/01/19 06:47:23 2012/01/19 07:47:23
```

this iMac shows twice :

```
10.56.9.70  c4:2c:03:06:87:87   host3   2012/01/19 05:58:55 2012/01/19 06:58:55
10.56.9.70  c4:2c:03:06:87:87   host3   2012/01/19 06:28:55 2012/01/19 07:28:55
```

this laptop shows 4 times, twice for LAN and twice for Wireless

```
10.56.9.87  ac:81:12:13:a5:ff   host4   2012/01/19 06:14:34 2012/01/19 07:14:34
10.56.9.47  1c:75:08:56:72:ba   host4   2012/01/19 06:14:35 2012/01/19 07:14:35
10.56.9.87  ac:81:12:13:a5:ff   host4   2012/01/19 06:44:34 2012/01/19 07:44:34
10.56.9.47  1c:75:08:56:72:ba   host4   2012/01/19 06:44:35 2012/01/19 07:44:35
```

Answer (score 2):

Its normal behavior, and in your case you see different lease times too. Instead of constantly rewriting the entire leases file the dhcp daemon just appends to the end. When it restarts it reads the last records for each entry to build its active database.

Check the second paragraph under the *Format* topic at dhcpd.leases(5) manpage:
http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.leases